# Is there a way for the developer to highlight browser (f3) search results on a website in a different color than default?

Tags: css, google-chrome, full-text-search, microsoft-edge, user-agent

I'm building a website that has a bright yellow in it's color scheme. The scheme can not be altered. In some places it is used to highlight text. Now I recognized that the yellow is exactly the same as the one that highlights your search terms, when you use the F3 search within a website and since it's text heavy content, I believe it will lead to usability issues and confusion for some users.

Is there a way to override the color the browser search uses to highlight text (like values in the user-agent-stylesheet or a js library) or is this baked into the software without any possible way to interfere?

Answer (score 2):

There is [::selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection), but the only browser that utilizes it for search result highlighting seems to be Edge (EdgeHTML), and even then it is only for active result - not all results.

```css
::selection {
  background-color: #9900ff;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
Search, search
```

Furthermore, there's a bit of a spread between how browsers implement this to begin with,

- Chromium uses orange for active result, yellow for rest.
- Edge uses ::selection for active result, yellow for rest.
- Firefox uses green for active result, purple for rest.

As an ultimate workaround, you could implement custom search via [markjs](https://markjs.io/) or alike, but it does seem like there should be some better way than this.